Python Embeddable Cython cythonize tools Error On Windows 10
I want to use a Embeddable version of Python, but I encountered an issue while using Cython tools.
I don't want to switch to the installation version.

cythonize utils.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "D:\Develop\python\Scripts\cythonize.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Develop\python\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 251, in main
    _cython_compile_files(all_paths, options)
  File "D:\Develop\python\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Cythonize.py", line 67, in _cython_compile_files
    ext_modules = cythonize(
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Develop\python\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1010, in cythonize
    module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list(
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Develop\python\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 784, in create_extension_list
    from distutils.extension import Extension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils'

python312._pth content:
python312.zip
DLLs
Lib
Lib\..
Lib\site-packages
# Uncomment to run site.main() automatically
#import site

package list:
Package    Version
---------- -------
asgiref    3.8.1
Cython     3.0.10
Django     5.0.6
pip        24.1.1
setuptools 70.0.0
sqlparse   0.5.0
tzdata     2024.1
wheel      0.43.0

utils.py content:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# cython: language_level=3
import sys
def sayHello(name:str):
    print("sayHello utils:" + name)

I tried to add the cython path to python312.pth, but it was ineffective.

setuptools includes distutils so just pip install setuptools

I have installed setuptools
